# Using mesh analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis

If you're using mesh analysis, for each loop current do you have to have at least one node, where only that loop current through it?

For instance, if you have 2 loop currents, do you have to have at least two nodes where the current in node 1 is loop current 1 and the current in node 2 is loop current 2?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you imagine a 3-by-3 grid of small loops and consider the loop current in the center loop there is no element or node that has *only* that current flowing through it.

Comment: True, but you can define the loops in a way that there is at least one node for each loop current, can't you? I'm wondering because my book takes explicit measures to ensure that this condition is met.

Comment: Yes, there must be at least one node for each loop current but that's not what you asked. You asked if for each loop current there must be a node such that __only__ that current flows through that node. These are two much different things.